# Registering in COM+ expose less interfaces than Regsvr32

Tags: com, dcom

I've been using a 32 bit COM library by registering it with regsvr32 and all works fine. Since I need to access it from a 64 bit process, I'm now registering it as COM+ through the Component Services administrative tool. Problem is, it seems that not all of the COM interfaces are exposed anymore. What could be the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two aspects of this problem.

First, you manually control which classes are exposed through COM+ by adding these classes only into the COM+ application. The classes you don't include will be instantiated in-proc and this instantiation will just fail because of 32-bit/64-bit incompatibility.

Then comes marshaling. In order to give the consumer an interface pointer of the newly created object COM+ needs to know how to marshal that interface. Unless you implement marshalling on your own default marshalling is used. Default marshalling will work only if the following requirements are met: the COM server contains a type library, the interface is included into that type library and the interface is fully Automation-compatible. The latter roughly means that none of that interface's methods have parameters of custom types like structs for example (interfaces are okay). If these requirements are not met COM+ will return E_NOINTERFACE when the consumer invokes CoCreateInstance() or IUnknown::QueryInterface(). See this similar question: [What is required to enable marshaling for a COM interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852497/what-is-required-to-enable-marshaling-for-a-com-interface) You basically have three choices: not query the violating interface, implement custom marshalling (which I don't currently know where to start with) or introduce a new intermediate interface which would be Automation-compatible.